# iOS UITesting Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to run `Xcode` `UITesting` on a physical device (`iPod`), but am getting the error :

> Test Target UITests encountered an error (Early unexpected exit,
>   operation never finished bootstrapping-no restart will be attempted).

The specific line that is triggering the error is :

```
[[[XCUIApplication alloc] init] launch];
```

I have noticed that the `UITesting` app does not launch on the device, instead on the test target app is launching, which I assume is the issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this bug by altering the build settings, specifically bundle loader. I removed build/Debug-iphoneos/MY_APP.app/MY_APP from debug and build/Release-iphoneos/MY_APP.app/MY_APP. I then added a couple additional compile sources and was able to get the UITesting to function again.